# Map Kubernetes ingress subdomain host to path in service

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have the following ingress controller and the host that contains `api` answers to this url `https://api.example.com/docs`.

Now I would like to configure this nginx ingress access the `/docs` endpoint using `https://docs.example.com`. I have tried to use the annotation rewrite-target but I can't figure out how to accomplish this.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/acme-challenge-type: dns01
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: web-service
              servicePort: 80
    - host: api.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: api-service
              servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    secretName: example.com
```

Comment: Have you seen this [doc with an example](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/)?

Comment: @OhHiMark Yes, but I want to do it the other way around. I want `docs.example.com` to add `/docs` instead remove like they are doing in the example.

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is the [app-root annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#app-root). If you use something like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /docs
```

incoming requests at `example.com/` will be rewritten internally to `example.com/docs`.

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: I don't think that this would work because the app-root is changed for every host in my ingress. I only want docs.example.com to be affected. The perfect solution would be if files from /docs would be served from docs.example.com without the redirect. But if a redirect to /docs is needed it would do just fine

Comment: I see. In that case I think it would be best to create a separate Ingress for `docs.example.com` and use `app-root` **there only**. Would that be possible in your use case?